# How do I assign a set of numbers to a variable but the set of numbers will be randomly generated?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a set a random numbers, and then add these numbers after they have been generated. My code is very simple and looks like this

```
u = sample(x=1:10, size =5, replace = TRUE)
```

I basically want to say

u=set of numbers that will be generated

```
sum(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
u <- sum(sample(x=1:10, size =5, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it didn't work the first time, are "<-" and "=" not interchangeable?
It worked this time when I used "<-" instead of "='

Comment: @xsgtangle if it is inside the function, i.e. specifying the parameters, use `=`, and outside assignment do with `<-`

Comment: @xsgtangle and if that is the case then that is important info to mention when writing a question